# Best way to analyze how a conservation program is impacting the recovery of a conservation-dependent species

Tags: r, regression, generalized-linear-model, modeling, biostatistics

I am currently working on a paper that assesses the impact of conservation translocation on species recovery. For this, the datasheet that I prepared contains the following:
Dependent variable: Species population trend (quantitative: count data)
Independent variables: Years of conservation interventions, habitat availability (qualitative), successful nesting occurrences, and few others.
Kindly guide me as to which model would best fit my data. Can GAM work well with this data? Or will GLM using ordinal regression work better? Kindly help.

Comment: You really need to tell us more details!

Comment: @kjetil b halvorsen  The dependent variables are - species population trend, percent change in population. The independent variables are - Total areas/survey areas Effective use area Survey frequency (population monitoring since 1975) Current population Total adults RDI, Nesting success, Past population Trend,  Breeding population, Released individuals, Protection status, Protected area, Release Interval, Monitoring